# Jetpack Compose, how to reset LazyColumn position when new data are set?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I'm working on a search page made in Compose with `LazyColumn`, everything works fine except for the wanted behavior of `LazyColumn` returing to first item when data changes.

This is my actual implementation of lazy column:

```
@Composable
fun <DataType : Any> GenericListView(
    itemsList: SnapshotStateList<DataType>, // this list comes from the search page viewmodel
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    spacing: Dp = 24.dp,
    padding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    item: @Composable (DataType) -> Unit
) {

    val listState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(spacing),
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier.padding(padding)
    ) {
        items(itemsList) {
            item(it)
        }
    }

    SideEffect {
        Log.i("->->->->->->->", "side effect launched")
        coroutineScope.launch {
            listState.scrollToItem(0)
        }
    }
}
```

As docs says, `SideEffect` should be called everytime the function is recomposed,
but it appear to be working only in debug mode with breakpoints in `SideEffect`, otherwise, it works only when the whole page is first created.

I've already tried with `LaunchedEffect` instead of `SideEffect`, using `itemsList` as `key`, but nothing happened.

Why my code works only in debug mode ?
Or better, an already made working solution to reset position when new data are set ?

Answer (score 1):

`SideEffect` doesn't work because Compose is not actually recomposing the whole view when the `SnapshotStateList` is changed: it sees that only `LazyColumn` is using this state value so only this function needs to be recomposed.

To make it work you can change `itemsList` to `List<DataType>` and pass plain list, like `itemsList = mutableStateList.toList()` - it'll force whole view recomposition.

---

`LaunchedEffect` with passed `SnapshotStateList` doesn't work for kind of the same reason: it compares the address of the state container, which is not changed. To compare the items itself, you again can convert it to a plain list: in this case it'll be compared by items hash.

```
LaunchedEffect(itemsList.toList()) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the mentioned functionality with `SideEffect`, `remember` and with some kind of `identificator` (listId) of the list items. If this identificator changes, the list will scroll to the top, otherwise not.

I have extended your code. (You can choose any type for listId.)

```
@Composable
fun <DataType : Any> GenericListView(
    itemsList: SnapshotStateList<DataType>, // this list comes from the search page viewmodel
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    spacing: Dp = 24.dp,
    padding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
    listId: String? = null,
    item: @Composable (DataType) -> Unit
) {
    var lastListId: String? by remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }

    val listState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    LazyColumn(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(spacing),
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier.padding(padding)
    ) {
        items(itemsList) {
            item(it)
        }
    }

    SideEffect {
        Log.i("->->->->->->->", "side effect launched")
        coroutineScope.launch {
            if (lastListId != listId) {
                lastListId = listId
                listState.scrollToItem(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```